# how to pass java output as a matlab variable?

Tags: java, user-interface, function, matlab

I have written a Java program which is invoked using system() function, thus it runs on the command window of Matlab. Now I want to know if there's another way to run a Java program other than running it on command window? Can it be run on any user made GUI in Matlab? Another problem is, I want to know if my program has some string value as output, which is generally displayed on command window, how can i store it in variable in Matlab?

Hope to hear from you very soon.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hello World](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-195EX/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-195EX) solution by The MathWorks provides some insights on how to run a simple 'Hello World' java application inside MATLAB. You may change the Java code a bit, in order to have a method that returns a String.

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
    public String hello()
    {
        String helloWorld = "Hello World!";
        return helloWorld;
    }
}
```

Once this simple class is compiled and on the MATLAB JVM classpath create an instance and invoke the method with the following two commands.

```
o = HelloWorld
output = o.hello;
```

The String returned by the HelloWorld instance is assigned to the MATLAB variable `output`.

There is no need for a `system` command with Java code in MATLAB. You have direct access to the JVM from inside MATLAB. For an application with a complex GUI, break out to Java.

[Undocumented Java](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/category/java/) is a valuable source on MATLAB, Java and GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the classpath set is correct.

I modified the code, using it without main..

```
class HelloWorld
{
        public String Hello()
        {
            String helloWorld="Hello World!";
            return helloWorld;
        }
}
```

Now, as per guided i try to create instance obj in Matlab, with following command:

```
o = HelloWorld;
```

Here I get following err:

> ??? No constructor 'HelloWorld' with
>   matching signature found.

The next command indicated it this:

```
output = o.hello;
```

which wouldnt work unless instance is created.